# Missing encode info on XML header using XMLDOM

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, xmldom

i want to print xml header with xmldom. The problem is, it prints only the xml version but missing the encode information.

What i got :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

What i want:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

im using ORACLE 11g

And here is what i got so far:

```
doc     := xmldom.newdomdocument;
xmldom.setversion(doc,'1.0');        
xmldom.setCharset(doc,'UTF-8');
mainNode := xmldom.makeNode(doc);

rootElmt := xmldom.createElement(doc,'Dokument');
rootNode := xmldom.appendChild (mainNode,xmldom.makeNode(rootElmt));
SetCurNode (rootNode);

dbms_lob.createTemporary(vClob,true); 
dbms_xmldom.writeToClob (doc,vClob);
xmldom.freedocument  (doc);
```

Thanks in advance,

Ivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure why charset isn't included in the output, but it seems to be a common issue. One alternative (shown here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2791321000346652231) is to do the following:

```
xmldom.setVersion(doc,'1.0" encoding="UTF-8');
```

Edit: Apparently, the character set you specify is ignored unless you use the writeToFile procedure, this would explain why it is not being included in the output when using writeToClob